# How to apply query parameter constraints to grape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, ruby-grape

In Rails5 API, I was able to add Contraints to routes. For example;

```
GET /hello => hello#index
GET /hello?download => hello#download
```

As you can see both URLs are same. Only difference is second one has Constraint in it and if download parameter is in URL then it redirected to another action.

How can I make the same thing on Grape? I couldn't find any resource on their documentation nor issues list.

```
get :hello do
  'I am a hello world page'
end
```

but if URL has some query parameters that I predefined then I want to execute this:

```
get :hello do { ?download }
  'download a file (for example)'
end
```

I played with `params` and created a `requires` params. **Still first one catch the request.**

This is what I use on Rails API for route:

```
class DownloadConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    request.query_parameters.key?('download')
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:** I want to be more clear on this. I would like to use both route together. I know params bag can be used to require parameters before execution. What I am trying to achieve is I would like to set routes based on GET parameters. See Rails' advanced contraints: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

Answer (score 0):

Add a optional parameter and redirect if it was receieved:

```
params do
  optional :download
end

get :hello do
  redirect '/' if params[:download]
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not working. See, This requires :download parameter to be given. But what If I dont write that parameter? I want to redirect them to another action. I want to execute route based on parameters. I already gi,ve the contraint sample in my question. I would like to use `:hello` **with** and **without** parameter **separately**. If I use this, route says "download" is missing, If I not put it to URL. See here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I would handle it with an optional param and a redirect.

Comment: Its okay. I do not want to do HTTP redirect actually. I just would like to respond to requests directly just like we do in Rails. I am sure grape would have this option but I do not know how. If Rails can, grape can do too (I guess). Or maybe is there a way to internally redirect request to another method/route without redirecting user's browser or request.